# Como quebra linha após 29 digitos C#?

Tags: c#

Como faço para que a cada 29 digitos, a linha se quebre?

```
var hs = hs_codes.Text;
        var texto = new StringBuilder(hs.Length);
        var digito = true;

        foreach(var chr in hs)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(chr))
            {
                if (!digito) texto.Append(';');
                texto.Append(chr);
                digito = true;
            }
            else digito = false;
        }
        txt_alterado.ReadOnly = false;
        txt_alterado.Focus();

        txt_alterado.Text = Convert.ToString(texto);
```

Comment: Se quebre como?

Comment: a cada 29 digitos ela quebre na textbox, não estou conseguindo fazer com /n/r

Comment: `TextBox` não lida com quebra de linha.

Comment: Deve-se usar uma `RichTextBox` com a propriedade `MultiLine = true`.

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar o `Take` (utilizando a biblioteca `System.Linq`) para obter apenas o número de caracteres que quiser, e ir adicionando o texto com quebra de linha à `TextBox`:

```
// exemplo com texto fixo
string strText = "quebra de linha aos 29 caracteres; vamos ver se o código funciona em TextBox com Multiline = True!";

while (true)
{
    textBox1.AppendText($"{string.Concat(strText.Take(29))}{Environment.NewLine}");

    if (strText.Length >= 29)
        strText = strText.Substring(29);
    else break;
}
```

Pode ser um controlo `TextBox`, mas tem de ter a propriedade `Multiline` ativada.

Baseado neste exemplo só precisa depois adaptar às suas necessidades!

Answer (score 0):

Amigo não tenho certeza mais tente algo como isso....
Não se esqueça de habilitar o multiline

```
    var hs = hs_codes.Text;
    var texto = new StringBuilder(hs.Length);
    var digito = true;
    int i = 0; 
    foreach(var chr in hs)
    {
        if (char.IsDigit(chr))
        {

            if (!digito) texto.Append(';');
            texto.Append(chr);
            digito = true;
            if(i>27){
                i=0;
                texto.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            }
            i++;
        }
        else digito = false;
    }
    txt_alterado.ReadOnly = false;
    txt_alterado.Focus();

    txt_alterado.Text = Convert.ToString(texto);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer usando LINQ

Por exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string strText = "1234567890" + 
                         "ABCDEFGHIJ" + 
                         "1234567890" + 
                         "abcdefghij" + 
                         "1234567890";

        const int qtdQuebra = 10;
        var arrayTxrt = strText.Select((e, i) => ((i + 1) % qtdQuebra == 0) ? e + Environment.NewLine : e.ToString());  
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", arrayTxrt));
    }
}
```

<sup>**[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MCD9lN)**</sup>